# How to escape # in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I am reading data with the `sf` library (https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html)

```
cases <- read_sf(
    dsn = "foo.gpkg",
    query="SELECT \#ID FROM \"foo\""
)
```

Which gives me

> Error: '#' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""SELECT #"

Why does it recognize it as an expace character? I am using `\` to escape it.

Comment: completely tangential to the question, but whoever decided to name a column in database #id (with starting hashmark) should be hung, drawn & quartered...

Comment: Got this data send by someone else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you need double backslashes `\\` to escape special character.

```
cases <- read_sf(
    dsn = "foo.gpkg",
    query="SELECT \\#ID FROM \"foo\""
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a missing - " - :

```
cases <- read_sf(
  dsn = "foo.gpkg",
    query="SELECT \#ID FROM \"foo\""
)
```

Comment: ah well, that was a typo in my q